# Gulp CDNify Basic Example

Tags: javascript, gulp, cdn

I'm using gulp cdnify for the first time.  I'm starting with a simple example.  My HTML contains this:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my gulpfile contains the following:

```
var cdnizer = require("gulp-cdnizer");
gulp.src("index.html")
        .pipe(cdnizer([
            {
                file: 'js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js',
                cdn: 'google:jquery@2.1.3'
            }
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist));
});
```

The html in the resulting dist file looks like this:

```
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
js"></script><script>if(!(window.jQuery)) cdnizerLoad("js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I mess up?

Comment: do you use that module ? https://github.com/OverZealous/gulp-cdnizer

Comment: In fact, it s weird but seems correct given the README on github. Have you try to use another module such https://github.com/anhulife/gulp-cdn-absolute-path or https://github.com/kaiqigong/gulp-cdnify. To me, but i m nobody, gulp-cdnizer is weird. I did not get why it s working that way..

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have put the function in a task.

This will work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cdnizer = require("gulp-cdnizer");
gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.src("index.html")
       .pipe(cdnizer([
           {
               file: 'js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js',
               cdn: 'google:jquery@2.1.3'
            }
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist));
});
```

You then just run this by `gulp` in your terminal. It will run the default task.